# Dynamic Event Names in StencilJS based on Prop value

Tags: typescript, events, dynamic, stenciljs, listen

I am trying to create a general slider component using StencilJS. The idea I had was to pass a slider ID as a prop, then use the prop as the event name when the slider changes.

The problem is the listeners are not catching the dynamic events emitted with the prop names. I think it might have to do with the component lifecycle but I am not sure. Any Ideas?

```
export class ParentComponent{

    @Listen('slider_A')
    onSliderValueChangeA(){
        console.log('event A') //not logging on slider change
    }

    @Listen('slider_B')
    onSliderValueChangeB(){
        console.log('event B') //not logging on slider change
    }

    @Listen('slider_C')
    onSliderValueChangeC(){
        console.log('event C')//not logging on slider change
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div class='container'>
                <slider-input slider_id={'slider_A'} slider_title={'S1'} ></slider-input>
                <slider-input slider_id={'slider_B'} slider_title={'S2'} ></slider-input>
                <slider-input slider_id={'slider_C'} slider_title={'S3'} ></slider-input>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

Here is the slider component...

@Component({
    tag: 'slider-input',
    styleUrl: 'slider-input.scss',
    shadow: true
})

export class Slider{
    @Prop() slider_id: string;


    @Event({
        eventName: this.slider_id,
    }) on_slider_value_change: EventEmitter<null>;


    onValueChange(change){
        this.slider_value = change.value;
        this.on_slider_value_change.emit()
    }
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a better approach would be to emit the slider's ID as event data/detail instead, but anyway...

The listeners should work afaik, but the `@Event` decorator might not. You can try to create the events manually instead, using [`dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) and [`CustomEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent).

```js
export class MySlider {
  @Element() host: HTMLMySliderElement;

  onValueChange(change) {
    this.slider_value = change.value;

    this.host.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(this.slider_id));
  }

  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know dynamic event names are not possible in Stencil, possibly because the event name is interpreted before the component is loaded.

Instead you can attach the listeners directly to the elements:

```
export class Slider {
    @Prop() slider_id: string;

    @Event() valueChange: EventEmitter<null>;

    onValueChange(change){
        this.slider_value = change.value;
        this.valueChange.emit()
    }
]
```

```
export class ParentComponent{

    onSliderValueChange(id: string){
        console.log('event', id)
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div class='container'>
                <slider-input slider_id={'slider_A'} onValueChange={() => this.onSliderValueChange('A')} slider_title={'S1'} ></slider-input>
                <slider-input slider_id={'slider_B'} onValueChange={() => this.onSliderValueChange('B')} slider_title={'S2'} ></slider-input>
                <slider-input slider_id={'slider_C'} onValueChange={() => this.onSliderValueChange('C')} slider_title={'S3'} ></slider-input>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Or you could add the listener manually:

```
@Element() el: HTMLElement;

this.el.querySelector('slider-input').addEventListener('valueChange', e => {
  switch(e.currentTarget.slider_id) {
    case 'slider_A':
      console.log('event A');
      break;
    case 'slider_B':
      console.log('event B');
      break;
  }
});

// or

this.el.querySelector('slider-input[slider_id=slider_A]')
  .addEventListener('valueChange', () => console.log('event A');
```

Comment: Thank you for presenting me with this solution. This data binding with generalized input components is a key aspect of the entire project I'm working on, hence it was important enough to be my first stack overflow question.

I hope they do add dynamic event names in the future.

Comment: @StevenWoerpel I've added some more options.